# Anonymous function declarations cause Fast Refresh to not preserve local component state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, next.js

I'm using redux with next js and this is my reducer.

```
const initialState = {
    navBarShow: false
}

export default function pageData(state = initialState, action) {

    switch (action.type) {

        case 'SET_NAV_BAR':
            return {
                ...state,
                navBarShow: action.payload
            }
        default: return state
    }

}
```

I'm calling it inside reducers index.js like this.

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

import pageData from './PageContents' 

export default combineReducers({
    pageData,
});
```

But I'm getting this error,

> Anonymous function declarations cause Fast Refresh to not preserve
> local component state.
> C:\react\nextfinalcom\redux\reducers\PageContents.js Please add a name
> to your function, for example:
>
> Before export default function () { /* ... */ }
>
> After export default function Named() { /* ... */ }
>
> A codemod is available to fix the most common cases:
> https://nextjs.link/codemod-ndc

Can it be a cache issue since I added a name?. Is there a way to clear cache?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the `.next` folder and re-running the dev server?

Comment: @juliomalves That fixed it man thanks a lot